# Can I make Discovery or any other IBM service crawl the web for my chatbot?

Tags: web-crawler, watson, watson-discovery, watson-assistant

I want to connect Watson Discovery to a chatbot but as it turns out, our documents are updated very frequently and downloading and uploading statically isn’t cutting it. So I want to know if there is a way to make Discovery crawl the web, or if any other IBM service provides this capability.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible however will need some tinkering to do so, suggest looking at this as a starting point https://github.com/IBM-Watson/nutch-indexer-discovery the easiest way would be to have some form of database that the documents are regularly ingested into and then have discovery connect to that.